# Is it fair to say that the majority of alleles of a typical diploid organism are homologous at each locus?

Tags: zygosity

I'm trying to get an overview of when zygosity actually comes to bear in regard to the entire genome, the following statement represents my understanding so far...

> In a typical diploid organism, most of the genes/alleles on each locus are identical/homologous (say in the order of 95-99%) with the corresponding gene/allele on the other chromosome.
>   When compared to the overall genome, it is only on a relatively small number of genes/alleles where the degree of similarity of the alleles for a trait becomes an issue.

So in other words would it be fair to say that, for a typical diploid organism, most of the genes on each chromosome are identical to their counterpart, it is only on a relatively small number where differences occur. e.g. most of the genes/alleles in a pea plant are the same and the resulting traits can be easily predicted. It is only a relatively small number of genes e.g. the genes responsible for flower color in a pea plant, or eye color in humans that the issue of zygosity, and using statistical techniques like Punnet squares etc comes play?

Comment: Please cite some evidence that supports your assertion. SNPs are incredibly common and widespread, so that would seem to rule out your hypothesis right away, as any two alleles would *not* have 100% nucleotide identity.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks, its of course possible my statement was wrong, it was not something I had derived from a credible source I could site it was my intuitive "guess" at the role zygosity played in the larger overall context of the genome. Something that has been omitted from any biology lessons I have studied. It wouldn't surprise me that the answer to my question is *there is alot more going on and its more complicated than can be explained in a single statement*